# Cakephp setting id

Tags: php, cakephp

Okay so as far as i can understand using `$this->id` = `id` will set that your next request will get the row from the database with that id. (if you have followed the cake conventions).

Now i am trying to set a value and have therefore created the following function in my `Product` model

```
        $this->id = $product_id;
    $product = $this->find('first');
    $final_amount = $product['Product']['antal'] - $amount;
    $this->saveField('Product.antal',$final_amount);
```

However when i debug it then `$product` is not equal to the id i set. meaning it just took the first of the database table.

How come? and if this isnt the way to use `$this->id` what is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud assign a value to $this->id when you want to update that row id with Model::save(), or want to read from that row with Model::read(). Setting $this->id prior to Model::find() has no effect on select queries.

if you will call Model::find('first') most probably it will find the first record by ordering records by column whose name is assigned to orderBy class attribute of model, by default perhaps its the id field and ordering must be ASC.

Ideal scenarioes for using $this->id = $intVar would be as under:
when calling

```
Model::save()//for updating records
Model::saveField();
Model::read(); 
Model::delete();//for deleting
```

Answer (score 2):

After setting the `id`, you are supposed to use the `read` method. it will get the record you desired for.
You should call `$this->ModelName->read();`

Using the `find` have nothing to do with setting the id. it will simply find a record based on the options supplied.

Comment: One shouldn't use read() - especially not if one doesn't know what else happens when using this method. I would always prefer find() over read() in that case. Especially for beginners.

Comment: Yes
Note what @mark wrote, tho i think read() is just fine, you really should take a good read about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->findById('first', $product_id);
```

> Creating or updating is controlled by the model’s id field. If
>   $Model->id is set, the record with this primary key is updated.
>   Otherwise a new record is created [...]

More http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

**Edit:**

To update row try this;

```
$product = $this->findById('first', $product_id);
$final_amount = $product['Product']['antal'] - $amount;
$this->saveField('Product.antal',$final_amount);
```

Comment: maybe this will work but what is the point of $this->id then?

Comment: From what I know $this->id is for creating or updating row, not for find.

Comment: so how would i go around updating a row because thats exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

find(), as documented, uses conditions array to retrieve records

```
$product = $this->Product->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first

Sidenote:
`$this->id` is currently mainly used for saving records, to be able to easily read the new created primary key value (id).
It is also used for saving via saveField().

In your case then (after using find() to get the product array):

```
$this->Product->id = $product['Product']['id'];
$this->Product->saveField('antal', $final_amount);
```

Comment: Yeah but what if i want to update the exact field i have pulled? i simply want to manipulate that one column in that row

Comment: Nobody prevents you from writing your own [AppModel shortcut method](https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Model/MyModel.php#L1506) and just using `$this->Model->id = $id; $this->Model->get();` etc